# I need to create a system where user can login and logout. I am using netbeans and MYSQL database and GlassFish server 4.0

Tags: java, html, jsp, netbeans, requestdispatcher

I know it is a simple task but don't able to find out what is the problem.
I made one login.jsp which is starting page.
LoginAction.jsp which will validate the user 
I think there is some problem with ReqestDispatcher.
I am trying to find out solution from past 2 days and I am exhausted please help me.

All the table names and their field names are correct.

This is LoginAction.jsp

```
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="DataBase.DBCONNEction"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page import="javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%
            String uname = request.getParameter("name");
            String pass = request.getParameter("pass");

            String unam, upass;
            Connection con = null;

            PreparedStatement prst = null;
            Statement stm = null;
            DBCONNEction DBC = null;
            con = DBC.getConnection();
            stm = con.createStatement();
            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/welcome.jsp");
            ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery("select password from details where username = '" + uname + "'");
            if (rs.next()) { 
                if (rs.getString("password").equals(pass)) { //If valid password
                    session.setAttribute("User", uname); 
                }else { 
            request.setAttribute("Error", "Invalid password.");
                    rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/login.jsp");
                }
            } 
            else {
                request.setAttribute("Error", "Invalid user name.");
                rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/login.jsp");
            }

            rd.forward(request, response);
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is login.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Knowledge Repository System</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <h1>Knowledge Repository System JSP</h1>
            <form id="search" action="loginAction.jsp" method="POST">
                <label>Username <input type="text"  name="name" id="s-user" style="width:90%;" required></label>
                <label>Password<input type="password" name="pass" id="s-pass" style="width:90%;" required></label>
                <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </div>
        <a href="AdminLogin.html">Admin Panel</a>
        <div class="nav">
            <h2 style="font-size: 36px"><strong>Sign Up</strong></h2>
            <form action="details" method="POST">
                <signup>
                    <p><input type="text" name="name" required placeholder="Username"></p>
                    <p><input type="password" name="pass" required placeholder="password"></p>
                    <p><input type="text" name="email" required placeholder="xyz@abc.com"></p>
                    <p><input type="submit" value="Sign Up" align="center"></p>
                </signup>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is DBCONNEction.java

```
package DataBase;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;


public class DBCONNEction {

    private static String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/repository";
    private static String DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private static String pass = "myserver";
    private static String user = "root";
    static Connection con = null;

    static {
        try {
            Class.forName(DRIVER);
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, user, pass);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() {
        return con;
    }

}
```

Comment: That is a lot of uncompilable code .... Having Java code in a jsp without surrounded by <% %> ... won't work. Also: remove all the Java code from your jsp's and put it in servlets, your code will be a lot easier to read.

Comment: Sir please see now.
yes i can put that code in servlet and perform validation check
But why is it not working in jsp
It was working earlier but now i dont know why is it not working at all 
I am too confused and somewhat frustrated

Comment: Have you debugged and checked whether or not all the values are what you think they are?

Comment: yes sir it is perfectly doing the check with resulset but it is not forwarding request further

Comment: Right now i once again debugged

out.println("You are perfect");
i wrote this inside if user is valid region and it is working
i think that the problem is with dispatcher

Comment: You are using `forward` after printing html. That's not valid.

Comment: So i need to shift whole code before or after html tag??